# Why is python.exe so small?

Tags: python, linux, windows, interpreter

When I look into my python install folder, I see size of python.exe at 26kB. Dependency walker says, only dependency (beside msvcr and kernel32 dlls) is python33.dll, which has size around 72kB.

Looking on /usr/bin/pythopn3.2mu on my RPI debian installation, size of interpreter is 2.8MB.

What makes the difference between those sizes? What is different in loading libraries?

Comment: My python35.dll (from the normal python installer) is 3.1 MB.

Comment: You're looking at python3.dll in the DLLs directory. This is the stable Python 3 API that forwards to the implementation in python33.dll, which you'll find either in the installation directory beside python.exe for a per-user install or in the `%SystemRoot%\System32` directory for an all-users install. Note that, for 32-bit Python running on 64-bit Windows, the "System32" directory is dynamically redirected to "SysWOW64".

Comment: Also note that, starting with Python 3.5, the DLL is no longer installed to System32 for an all-users installation. It's always installed beside python.exe.

Comment: @eryksun you are correct. You should consider writing your comment as answer.